# Filter/unfilter angular table based on button-click

Tags: angularjs

I´ve been stuck for some time on a sortingfeature using angular. 
What I hope to achieve is the ability to filter `friends` by clicking one of the three buttons with ages.

Ex:
App starts with all friends showing. 
I click the button with `20` and only friends with age 20 shows.
I click 20 again   -> all friends show.

I have code similar to this:

http://plnkr.co/edit/iU2XjDsV2K8wThxdlZ8w?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';


 $scope.friends = [
    {name:'John', age:20, gender:'boy'},
    {name:'Jessie', age:30, gender:'girl'},
    {name:'Johanna', age:40, gender:'girl'},
    {name:'Joy', age:20, gender:'girl'},
    {name:'Mary', age:30, gender:'girl'},
    {name:'Peter', age:40, gender:'boy'},
    {name:'Sebastian', age:20, gender:'boy'},
    {name:'Erika', age:30, gender:'girl'},
    {name:'Patrick', age:40, gender:'boy'},
    {name:'Samantha', age:20, gender:'girl'}
  ];

  $scope.filterByAge = function(age) {
    // filter based on the age passed to this method
    // unfilter  (show all friends) if 'age' already
    //is the same as the argument
  };
});
```

And the view:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Sort by age</p>
    <button ng-click="filterByAge('20')">20</button>
    <button ng-click="filterByAge('30')">30</button>
    <button ng-click="filterByAge('40')">40</button>

    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="x in friends">
          <td>{{ x.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ x.age }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you first need to filter:

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in friends | filter:theFilter">
```

So, you need `theFilter` to exist in the scope, and by default, it shouldn't filter anything:

```
$scope.theFilter = {};
```

Now, when `filterByAge()` is called, it should modify the filter so that it filters by the given age:

```
$scope.filterByAge = function(age) {
  $scope.theFilter.age = age;
};
```

Except you want that, if the button is clicked again, and the filter already filters by that age, then the filtering is cancelled. So you want

```
$scope.filterByAge = function(age) {
  if ($scope.theFilter.age === age) {
    $scope.theFilter = {};
  }
  else {
    $scope.theFilter.age = age;
  }
};
```

Here's your plunkr doing it: http://plnkr.co/edit/atbvQ6lbUJmyq9ZJfmCj?p=preview